# Google Colab内のパッケージpymc3のバージョン表示が合わない

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
!pip list
```

でpymc3のバージョンを確認すると 3.8 となっているのですが、

```
import pymc3 as pm
print(pm.__version__)
```

とすると 3.7 と出力されます。どうすれば、3.8でインストールできますか？

Comment: 私のアカウントの Google Colab で `!pip install pymc3` してインストールされたのは `!pip list` も `pm.__version__` も 3.7 の pymc3 で、問題が再現できませんでした。インストールは `!pip install` でなさいましたか？

Answer (score 1):

セルの実行順序の関係で古い情報が表示されている可能性があります。上のメニュー、「ランタイム」から「再起動して全てのセルを実行」することで、上のセルから順番に実行し直してみてください。

Comment: !pip install --upgrade pymc3==3.8としたと思います。「再起動して全てのセルを実行」を行ったところ両方 3.7になりました

Comment: 「思います」ということは今のセルには `!pip install --upgrade pymc3==3.8` が入力されていないということですね？　ますます実行順序の問題な気がしてきました。上の方のセルに 3.8 をインストールするスクリプトを書いて再度「再起動して全てのセルを実行」すれば 3.8 に揃いませんでしょうか。

Comment: 直りました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 良かったです =)　もし良ければ、回答左側にあるチェックマークを押して回答を承認していただけると嬉しいです。